# Dynamic array, passing addresses

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, dynamic, pass-by-reference

I want to make a function which has in parameter an array of two dimensions that I dynamically allocated, the problem is that I don't know how to build my function.

Here is what I have in my main(N_MAX is defined as 300):

```
int i;
int **Bord = NULL;

Bord = malloc(N_MAX * sizeof(*Bord));
if(Bord == NULL)
{
    printf("Error while allocating memory to an array");
    free(Bord);
    return -1;
}
for(i = 0; i < N_MAX; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
    Bord[i] = malloc(N_MAX * sizeof(*(Bord[i])));
    if(Bord[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while allocating memory to an array");
        while(i != 0)
        {
            free(Bord[i]);
            i--;
        }
        free(Bord);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I've tried to do something with an array that is not dynamically allocated but it's really bad. When I want to debug the function I have the watches that works (I have the right number in my array) but the program doesn't work (error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int'))

I've already did some searches on Google but I can't find a topic with "dynamic allocation" and "pass by reference", if it exists please let me know.

How to buid this function?

Comment: What should your new function do?

Comment: You are creating an array of pointers to arrays if integers; you are not creating a 2D array because all the elements in a 2D array are contiguous.  Both can be accessed using two subscripts, but the underlying data is quite different.

Comment: It's a little but hard to explain, but in the array there is a picture and on this picture there is lines. The program has to follow these lines. So the function takes one coordinate of the line and look for what is around this point. at the end it returns the coordinates of the following point.

Comment: So, if they are not contiguous how can I pass my array by reference? Is it possible to do it?

Comment: You can pass the pointer to the start of the array of pointers to a function; the pointers in the array are contiguous with each other. The integers in each of the arrays of integers (allocated in the second loop) are stored contiguously; however, there is no guarantee that the integers in `Bord[0]` are contiguous with those in `Bord[1]`. You will need to pass an `int **data` to your function. You can then access the elements of the arrays using double subscripts: `data[i][j]` etc. However, the assembler code is quite different from what using `int (*data)[N_MAX]` (a pointer to an array) uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple program that illustrates two functions — `init_array()` that initializes an array after it is created by (more or less) the code in the question, and `print_array()` that prints the values in the array.  Apart from a reasonable separation of duties, the two functions show that what is set in the `init_array()` is visible in the `print_array()` function.  There's also a tiny function `free_array()`, made `static inline`, which releases the allocated data for an array — it handles both partially and fully allocated arrays.  All functions except `main()` are marked `static` since there is no other file that needs to see any of the functions.  Note that for ease of testing, I set `N_MAX` to 8, rather than 300.  Now I know it is working, it would be feasible and maybe sensible to set `N_MAX` to 300.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static void print_array(int **base);
static void init_array(int **base);

enum { N_MAX = 8 };

static inline void free_array(int n_rows, int **array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; i++)
        free(array[i]);
    free(array);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int **Bord = NULL;

    srand(time(0));     // Not good, but better than nothing

    Bord = malloc(N_MAX * sizeof(*Bord));
    if (Bord == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while allocating %zu bytes of memory\n", N_MAX * sizeof(*Bord));
        return -1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N_MAX; i++)
    {
        Bord[i] = malloc(N_MAX * sizeof(*(Bord[i])));
        if (Bord[i] == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while allocating %zu bytes of memory\n", N_MAX * sizeof(*Bord[i]));
            free_array(i, Bord);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    init_array(Bord);
    print_array(Bord);
    free_array(N_MAX, Bord);
    return 0;
}

static void init_array(int **base)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N_MAX; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N_MAX; j++)
            base[i][j] = (100 * (i + 1)) + (10 * (j + 1)) + rand() % 10;
    }
}

static void print_array(int **base)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N_MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d]:", i);
        for (int j = 0; j < N_MAX; j++)
            printf(" %3d", base[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Note that it uses `time()` to initialize the random number generator, so it should usually generate a new set of numbers each time it is invoked, unless you invoke it multiple times in a single second.

```
[0]: 115 121 137 142 159 166 175 181
[1]: 211 224 239 248 253 265 277 283
[2]: 316 320 337 349 357 364 376 380
[3]: 419 428 439 448 451 469 476 484
[4]: 511 527 534 544 558 569 578 585
[5]: 616 623 631 647 650 664 671 688
[6]: 710 729 739 748 759 766 779 783
[7]: 817 824 839 847 850 860 878 881
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've rewrote my function and now it works. I just have one more question, `inline` means that it will be faster to execute, right? That's what I read on another thread. Thank you

Comment: Using `inline` is a hint to the compiler that Jayne this function should be written into the functions that call it, rather than being a separate function. It can lead to improved performance. It isn’t wholly clear that’s important here, but it is small enough that it might help.  But it is unlikely that you’d be able to measure the difference in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to guess as to what your 'new' function will look like, lets correct the (many) problems with the posted code.

```
// added missing `#include` statements
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// added missing definition of N_MAX
#define N_MAX 300 

int main( void )  // corrected signature for 'main'
{
    //int i;
    // minimize the scope of variables

    int **Bord = NULL;

    //edited following line
    Bord = malloc(N_MAX * sizeof(*Bord));
    if(Bord == NULL)
    {
        //printf("Error while allocating memory to an array");
        // error messages should be output to 'stderr', not 'stdout'
        // suggest:
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        //free(Bord);  DONT do this, the allocation was not successful
        return -1;
    }

    // implied else, malloc was successful

    for( int i = 0; i < N_MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", i);

        Bord[i] = malloc(N_MAX * sizeof(*(Bord[i]));
        if(Bord[i] == NULL)
        {
            //printf("Error while allocating memory to an array");
            // error messages should be output to 'stderr', not 'stdout'
            // suggest:
            perror( "malloc failed" );

            //while(i != 0)
            // this will not free the first sub allocation
            // suggest
            i--;
            while( i >= 0 )
            {
                free(Bord[i]);  
                i--;
            }

            free(Bord);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // the following will result in a memory leak
    // because all those memory allocations have not been passed to 'free()'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your 'improvement' in `//Bord = malloc(N_MAX * sizeof(*Bord));` — `// don't want to allocate room for a bunch of 'int's` — `// do want to allocate room for a bunch of pointers` — `Bord = malloc( N_MAX * sizeof( Bord ) );` is not an improvement but a retrograde step.  Since pointer to `int` and pointer to pointer to `int` have the same size, you won't actually encounter an error, but the notation `SomeType *data = malloc(number * sizeof(*data));` is the correct idiom and your replacement is not.  The difference would matter if `SomeType` was a big structure.

Comment: OK, I'll modify my answer

Comment: Note that `free(Bord);` in the error path is merely pointless, not harmful.  Freeing a null pointer is a no-op apart from the unnecessary function call.  I agree that the `while (i != 0)` loop does not release the zeroth array.  I'd be very tempted to use just `while (i > 0) free(Bord[--i]);` for the loop, though.  This doesn't attempt to free the just failed allocation (a no-op again since the pointer is null), and does clean up the zeroth element and doesn't repeat itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Yes my code was not correct I just put what was in my "main".
Jonathan, I think my mistake is in, how to call the function `function(int **array)` and later in my code I'm writting `function(Bord);`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is it correct how I am calling my function? Should I do it in another way or define my function differently? Thank you for your help

Comment: The `@` is crucial in attracting attention.  If you have defined `function(int **array)`, then the correct call is `function(Bord)`, yes.  I would pass the dimension(s) of the array too, but you might decide not to if that size is fixed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But when I'm doing this in my function the array is impossible to use I have a `SIGSEV` When I'm debuging it in the watches I write `***array[0][0]` and there I have the correct number corresponding to the array but in my program it doesn't work... I have this error when I compile it: `error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')`

Comment: @Asusio: You've not shown your calling code, or your function, so it is impossible for us to guess what you've done wrong. As an expression, `***array[0][0]` implies five levels of indirection — which has blown my mind.  We can't help you debug code we can't see.  Please edit your question to add your best effort at the function.  It could sensibly arrange to initialize and print the value.  You could sensibly set `N_MAX` to 5 or perhaps 10 while you're debugging and getting the code working.  Changing that to 300 later will be trivial — as long as you're careful.